# find the greatest number in string and its index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, my thirst for awesome oneliners is not quenched yet..

I have

```
var a = "2:3:9:5";
```

I want to find the biggest number and its index.

in this case: `9` and index `2`.

what is the complicated and awesome way to do this?

I tried:

```
var biggest_number = Math.max.apply(Math, a.split(':'));
```

Comment: BTW: That's string, not array

Comment: @hindmost that didnot really matter, but I changed it thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var a = "2:3:9:5";
var arr = a.split(":");
var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
var index = arr.indexOf(max.toString());
```

Comment: I'm getting `index = -1`

Comment: @YerkoPalma because, it should be ``arr.indexOf(max.toString())``;

Comment: @doniyor, please update your answer to match the desired output

Comment: @RobertRozas it is not my answer :)

Comment: yes guys, you are right. arr contains strings. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/inzamamtahir/qh5ghhtp/1/)

Have a look at my method of finding the maximum number and it's index:

```
var a = "2:3:9:5";
var newArr = [];
var counter = 0;
var num = 0;
var split = ':';  
var max = 0;
var indexOfMax = 0;

for(var i = 0; a[i] != null; i++)
{
    if(a[i] != split)
    {
        newArr[counter] = a[i];
        counter++;
    }
}

for(var i = 0; newArr[i] != null; i++)
{
    num = parseInt(newArr[i]);
    if(max < num)
    {
        max = num;
        indexOfMax = i;
    }
}
alert(max);
alert(indexOfMax);
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, a.split(':')), a.split(':').indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, a.split(':')).toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
var a = "2:3:9:5";
a_array = a.split(':').sort().reverse();
a_array[0];
```

Comment: and how you get the index?

Answer (score 0):

The below code does what you need:

```js
var a = "2:3:9:5";
var arr = a.split(":");
var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
var str_max=""+max;
var index = arr.indexOf(str_max);
document.write(max);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(index);
```